# PyPI /simple not providing latest version of package

Tags: pip, pypi

I uploaded [a library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyRoblox/) to PyPI last night -- it is currently on version 0.0.3. When attempting to install the library with pip, version 0.0.1. is installed. Running `pip install pyroblox --upgrade`, pip determines 0.0.1 is the latest version. The same with uninstalling and then reinstalling. I thought this might be a caching issue, but when doing a verbose install, I saw that pip was checking this URL for the latest version:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyroblox/

The /simple page only contains version 0.0.1 -- not 0.0.2 or 0.0.3. It's been 15 hours since I uploaded version 0.0.2, so I don't think it's an issue of PyPI just running a slow cron job to update the /simple page.

Is there something extra I have to do when uploading packages to PyPI to get them to update on the /simple page? Right now I'm running `python setup.py sdist` and then `twine upload dist/pyRoblox-x-x-x.tar.gz`. This seems to update the normal page just fine, but /simple is stuck on 0.0.1. I can install the package from the source directly, but I want installing via pip to function correctly so I can distribute the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/simple started showing the latest versions after 24 hours. I guess there's an insanely long delay on its updates?